# Javascript issue with returning a object

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

```
var scratchData = [   
  {name: 'Billy Boy', grade: 'D'},
  {name: 'Serious Sara', grade: 'B'},  
  {name: 'Tepid Tom', grade: 'C'} ];  


function makeStudentsReport(data)
```

How can i make this function return a string that say name + 'is getting an' + grade; I must return an object.

Comment: do you need an array with the strings?

Comment: Return an Object or return a string? What did you try?

Comment: return a object. I've tried console.log(scratchData.name +'is getting an' + scratchData.grade)

Comment: You need to loop or map the array. `for (var i=0;i<scratchData.length;i++) { console.log(scratchData[i].name+' is getting a(n) '+ scratchData[i].grade); }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could map the result strings with [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

```js
function makeStudentsReport(data)  {
    return data.map(function (a) {
        return a.name + ' is getting a' + ('AEF'.indexOf(a.grade) === -1 ? "" : "n" ) + ' ' + a.grade;
    });
}

var scratchData = [{ name: 'Billy Boy', grade: 'D' }, { name: 'Serious Sara', grade: 'B' }, { name: 'Tepid Tom', grade: 'C' }, { name: 'Jet Jane', grade: 'A' }];

console.log(makeStudentsReport(scratchData));
```

Comment: `..is getting a"+("AEF".indexOf(a.grade)==-1?"n":"") + a.grade`

Comment: @mplungjan, nice catch. but result strings are reversed.

Comment: Ah. !=-1  as I had when I wrote it, then I swapped it but forgot to swap the n too

Comment: i used the .map method and it worked!! Thank you for your help!!

Answer (score 0):

Well David, you can use the map function as well as Nina did, or you can just use the typical for loop way:

```
var scratchData = [   
  {name: 'Billy Boy', grade: 'D'},
  {name: 'Serious Sara', grade: 'B'},  
  {name: 'Tepid Tom', grade: 'C'} ];

var get = ' is getting an '; // declaring it with var so it's easier to use

function makeStudentsReport(data) { // data  will be the array
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
        var everyObject = data[i]; //  everyObject is every object in the array
        console.log(everyObject.name + get + everyObject.grade);
    }
}
makeStudentsReport(scratchData); // passing the array as a parameter to the function
```

Or more simple you can use Array.forEach() method:

```
function makeStudentsReport(data) {
    data.forEach(function(object){
        console.log(object.name + get + object.grade);
    });
}

makeStudentsReport(scratchData);
```